# Xcode 14.0 Command PhaseScriptExecution failed

Tags: ios, xcode, build, xcode14

After updating Xcode to 14.0 (and accompanying Xcode Command Line Tools), and building my application as I normally would, I'm running into the error you see above. This is a pretty well documented error, but I've tried every solution I've been able to find:

- Investigating Keychain settings
- Running `pod deintegrate` and `pod install`
- Cleaning the build folder
- Logging off and shutting everything down and turning things back on / logging back in
- Entering `arm64` as an excluded architecture and subsequently removing it from the `.xcworkspace`
- Combinations of all the above
- Ensuring all the Pods I have are **not** out of date.

I'm at a loss. Your input is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

[image]

Comment: Open the full build log from the Report Navigator to see which build step has failed. Perhaps you'll see a more detailed error there.

Comment: Please post whole report.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, there was a file generated as part of the build process (I don't know exactly what) with some flag set that I didn't think I needed, so I just deleted it and rebuilt the app. No issues there.

Solution: it helps to comb through staged commits to see if there's anything created that simply isn't needed, and to delete those files ad hoc.